# VB6 function issue in the return expression "end of statement expected"

Tags: vb6

I am new to vb6 and I get a compiler error in my function when trying to return my variable.

> "end of statement expected error vb6"

my function goes as following:

```
Public Function StringFormat(ByVal MyStr As String) As String
   
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim sBadChar As String
   Dim NewString As String
   
   ' List all illegal/unwanted characters
   sBadChar = "/<>?\{}[]()=,!#*:'*¬-"

   ' Loop through all the characters of the string
   For i = 1 To Len(MyStr)
       If InStr(sBadChar, Mid(MyStr, i, 1)) Then
           Mid(MyStr, i, 1) = ""
       End If
   Next i
   
   Return MyStr
   
End Function
```

I get the error on the `return`, any ideas as of why this happens?
thank you in advance

Comment: *"I am new to vb6..."* No one should be new to VB6. :-) It's a dead technology. (VBA is still active, though.) If you're new to programming, FWIW I suggest studying something more modern, like VB.Net.

Comment: What line is the error complaining about? My VB6 is very rusty, but I suspect you want to compare the result of `InStr` with something, e.g. `If InStr(sBadChar, Mid(MyStr, i, 1) > 0`. But it might also be complaining about `Mid(MyStr, i, 1) = ""`, I don't recall whether that's valid in VB6, but I suspect not. You probably want `MyStr = Left(MyStr, i - 1) & Mid(MyStr, i)` Note that you'll also have to handle the fact that `i` is now too far ahead (because the string got shorter). You could fix that by looping backward rather than forward (`For i = Len(MyStr) To 1 Step -1`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Yes I only have a few months of programming and I prefer java or python but the biggest software we provide is still written in vb6 this is why I said I was new to VB6.  we are converting everything to VB.NET :) 
thanks for your feedback I think Johns answer is working fine for me.

Comment: We always forget there is a huge base of VB6 code in production.  It's not going away anytime soon, and someone has to maintain it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be:

```
Public Function StringFormat(ByVal MyStr As String) As String
   
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim sBadChar As String
   Dim NewString As String
   
   ' List all illegal/unwanted characters
   sBadChar = "/<>?\{}[]()=,!#*:'*¬-"

   ' Loop through all the characters of the string

       For i = 1 To Len(MyStr)
           If InStr(sBadChar, Mid(MyStr, i, 1)) Then
               Mid(MyStr, i, 1) = ""
           End If
       Next i
       
       StringFormat = MyStr 
      
    End Function
```

Comment: That was typed in a hurry. I should have added that the Return statement is only used to end  a GoSub routine in VB6 and I can't recall ever using GoSub in all the years I've been using VB6! :^)

Comment: John is right, but to put it another way: whereas in VB.NET you assign the return value of a function with the `Return` keyword, in VB6 (and VBA) you assign the function's name the return value: `<Function name> = <return value>`, i.e. in this case `StringFormat = MyStr`

Comment: Having never used VB.Net I wouldn't know, but I'm not in the least bit surprised! Another way that MS broke the conversion between the two! :^))